# REPLACE VIEW alternative in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Is there `REPLACE VIEW` alternative in clickhouse?
If I drop view and create it again, could I get some queries failed due to downtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create or replace?**

```
create or replace view testv as select 1;
create or replace view testv as select 2;
select * from testv
┌─2─┐
│ 2 │
└───┘
```

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2019.md

```
ClickHouse Release 19.5.2.6, 2019-04-15
   Support for CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW. 
   Allow to create a view or set a new definition in a 
   single statement. #4654 (Boris Granveaud)
```